# How to get all contacts of an Account and build an email List in MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I've an account Id, and would like to get the collection of contacts under the account to build an email list.

---

```
    //build up Email
    private Email BuildEmail(ActivityParty allcontacts){.... build my emailhere}

    private List<Entity> GetAllContactsFromAccountId(Guid accountId, List<Entity> toList)
    {          

        //how can I get all the contacts here
        foreach (Entity contact in Account.Contact.Entities)//????
        {
            Entity activityParty = new Entity("activityparty");
            activityParty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("??", e.Id);

            if (toList.Any(t => t.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid").Id == e.Id)) continue;

            toList.Add(activityParty);
        }

        return toList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Account key "parentcustomerid" in contact entity. you can get contact collection by account id as below.

```
  private EntityCollection getContactByAccountId(IOrganizationService service, Guid accountId)
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "contactid", "fullname" });
        query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("parentcustomerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountId))
        return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but it gives me conversion error. For e.g. When, I return this as entitycollection in a custom workflow to TargetOutput ref... ("contact") I get and Error cannot convert `entitycollection` to `entityreference`

Comment: I think you can use Out put parameter of EntityCollection type. like  [Output("Contacts")]
        [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
        public OutArgument<EntityCollection> Contacts { get; set; }.
And obviously you cannot set entityCollection object to an entityReference.